# How do I match what's between the quotes excluding these?

Tags: regex

I want to match what's between the quotes but excluding these. I tried positive and negative lookahead, which works for the end quote but I cannot exclude the first one. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the example I'm using:

```
  A: $("div"),
  B: $("img.some_class"),
  B: $("img.some_class.another_class"),
  C: $("#some_id"),
  D: $(".some_class"),
  E: $("input#some_id"),
  F: $("div#some_id.some_class.some_other"),
  G: $("div.some_class#some_id")
```

Here is my regex so far:

```
/(?!").*(?=")/g
```

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/\("\K[^"]+/g
```

`\K` means that the return value will start here.

For example, it will find: `A: $("div` but return as match just: `div`.
[Here Is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DFmLxN/1)

Comment: That was  what have you wanted?

Comment: @IMSoP. I added explaining of it. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

There are not two, but *four* different lookaround modifiers, because you need to specify two different aspects:

- Are you asserting that something *is* there (positive) or *is not* there (negative)?
- Are you asserting that it's *before* the specified pattern (lookbehind) or *after* it (lookahead)?

The four combinations are generally written like this:

- `?=` for positive lookahead
- `?!` for negative lookahead
- `?<=` for positive lookbehind
- `?<!` for negative lookbehind

You've used a *negative lookahead* when you wanted a *positive lookbehind*, so the fixed version of what you wrote would be:

```
/(?<=").*(?=")/g
```

Beware the "greediness" of `.*`, which will match *as much of the string as possible*; you might want to use `.*?` to make it "non-greedy", or explicitly say "anything other than a quote mark" (`[^"]*`).

Another approach is to match the quotes normally, rather than with a lookaround, but "capture" the part between them: `/"(.*?)"/`. How you get to the "captured group" will vary depending on your programming language / tool, which you haven't specified.

Comment: Do you suggest a better way then?

Comment: @Albert I've added a couple of additional suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `(?!").*(?=")` first asserts what is directly on the right is not a double quote `(?!")` which succeeds because for the example data that is a `$`.

Then `.*` is greedy and will match 0+ times any character except a newline and will match until the end of the string. Then it will backtrack to fulfill the assertion `(?=")` where directly on the right is a double quote.

If a positive lookbehind is supported, you might change the `(?!")` to `(?<=")` and the pattern could look like `(?<=\$\(")[^"]+(?="\))` to not match empty double quotes.

Taking the dollar sign and the opening and closing parenthesis into account, you could use a capturing group and a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^"]+` to match any char except a double quote:

```
\$\("([^"]+)"\)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5JUDzV/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using lookahead and lookbehinds as you asked :

```
/(?<=").*(?=")/g
```

Test Here : https://regex101.com/r/kCEuow/2

You might also consider using substrings :

```
/"([^"]+)"/g
```

Test the regex : https://regex101.com/r/kCEuow/1